# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching DocumentTermMatrix(::Vector{String})

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, julia

I am trying to train a basic SVM model for multiclass text classification in Julia. My dataset has around 75K rows and 2 columns (text and label). The context of the dataset is the abstracts of scientific papers gathered from PubMed. I have 10 labels in the dataset.

The dataset looks like this:

[image: Dataset]

I keep receiving two different Method errors. The starting one is:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching DocumentTermMatrix(::Vector{String})
```

I have tried:

```
convert(Array,data[:,:text])
```

and also:

```
convert(Matrix,data[:,:text])
```

Array conversion gives the same error, and matrix conversion gives:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (Matrix)(::Vector{String})
```

My code is:

```
using DataFrames, CSV, StatsBase,Printf, LIBSVM, TextAnalysis, Random

function ReadData(data)
    df = CSV.read(data, DataFrame)
    return df
end

function splitdf(df, pct)
    @assert 0 <= pct <= 1
    ids = collect(axes(df, 1))
    shuffle!(ids)
    sel = ids .<= nrow(df) .* pct
    return view(df,sel, :), view(df, .!sel, :)
end

function Feature_Extract(data)
    Text =   convert(Array,data[:,:text])
    m = DocumentTermMatrix(Text)
    X = tfidf(m)
    return X
    
end

function Classify(data)
    data = ReadData(data)
    
    train, test = splitdf(data, 0.5)  
    ytrain = train.label
    ytest  = test.label

    Xtrain = Feature_Extract(train)
    Xtest = Feature_Extract(test)
    
    model = svmtrain(Xtrain, ytrain)
    ŷ, decision_values = svmpredict(model, Xtest);

    @printf "Accuracy: %.2f%%\n" mean(ŷ .== ytest) * 100
end

data = "data/composite_data.csv"

@time Classify(data)
```

I appreciate your help to solve this problem.

EDIT:

I have managed to get the corpus but now facing DimensionMismatch Error:

```
 using DataFrames, CSV, StatsBase,Printf, LIBSVM, TextAnalysis, Random

function ReadData(data)
    df = CSV.read(data, DataFrame)
    #count = countmap(df.label)
    #println(count)
    #amt,lesslabel = findmin(count)
    #println(amt, lesslabel)
    #println(first(df,5))
    return df
end

function splitdf(df, pct)
    @assert 0 <= pct <= 1
    ids = collect(axes(df, 1))
    shuffle!(ids)
    sel = ids .<= nrow(df) .* pct
    return view(df,sel, :), view(df, .!sel, :)
end

function Feature_Extract(data)
    crps = Corpus(StringDocument.(data.text))
    update_lexicon!(crps)
    m = DocumentTermMatrix(crps)
    X = tf_idf(m)
    return X
    
end

function Classify(data)
    data = ReadData(data)
    #println(labels)
    #println(first(instances))
    
    train, test = splitdf(data, 0.5)  
    ytrain = train.label
    ytest  = test.label

    Xtrain = Feature_Extract(train)
    Xtest = Feature_Extract(test)
    
    model = svmtrain(Xtrain, ytrain)
    ŷ, decision_values = svmpredict(model, Xtest);

    @printf "Accuracy: %.2f%%\n" mean(ŷ .== ytest) * 100
end

data = "data/composite_data.csv"

@time Classify(data)
```

Error:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("Size of second dimension of training instance\n matrix (247317) does not match length of\n labels (38263)")
```

Comment: `DocumentTermMatrix` expects `Corpus`, see https://juliatext.github.io/TextAnalysis.jl/dev/corpus/.

Comment: Can i iteratively create create a corpus based on may existing dataframe?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your data but it seems that `Corpus(StringDocument.(data.text))` should work.

Comment: Works like a charm. I edited the question, now have DimensionMismatch error.

Comment: You need to return `permutedims(X)` from `Feature_Extract` (i.e. you tried to supply incorrectly transposed feature matrix to the model).

Answer (score 0):

(*Copying Bogumił Kamiński's solution from the comments, as a community wiki answer, for better visibility.*)

The argument to `DocumentTermMatrix` should be of type `Corpus`, as in [this example](https://juliatext.github.io/TextAnalysis.jl/stable/features/#Creating-a-Document-Term-Matrix-1).

A `Corpus` can be created [with](https://juliatext.github.io/TextAnalysis.jl/stable/corpus/):

```
Corpus(StringDocument.(data.text))
```

There's a `DimensionMismatch` error after that, which is due to the mismatch between what `tf_idf` sends and what `svmtrain` expects. `tf_idf`'s return value has one row per document, whereas `svmtrain` expects one column per document i.e. expects each *column* to be an `X` value. So, performing a `permutedims` on the result before passing it to `svmtrain` resolves this mismatch.